# Make child windows inherit parent background color?

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, winapi

Is there a way for windows created with WS_CHILD to inherit the parent's background color rather than default to Dialog Color? I'm trying to do this for a tab control, mainly the part that extends due to the tabs not filling up the area. I want this color  to be the parent window's BG.

Thanks

Comment: Would using the transparent color work in your case?

Comment: I tried WS_EX_TRANSPARENT and it had no effect

Comment: There may be more you have to do besides just setting that flag from what i've gleaned by googling (i'm barely a novice at win32).

Comment: are you suggesting I have to get into ownerdrawing?

Comment: I don't know... You might be able to retrieve the hbrBackground from the window class somehow. Although, that won't help if the window does its own drawing on top of that.

Comment: How could I try getting the hbrbackground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "content" of the tab, you would call [EnableThemeDialogTexture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773320(VS.85).aspx) (Visual Styles can have complex tab content backgrounds), for the area to the right of the actual tabs I think you might have to owner draw (TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style) unless just using the TCS_RIGHTJUSTIFY style is enough.